# MVC4 WEB API project in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a project of WEB API MVC 4. When i run this project in vs 2010, it says this project is incompatible with current version of visual studio. i have made it in vs 2012 but now i need to run this project in vs 2010 for some other purpose. Please guide me how to make this possible. thanx in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a new Web API project in VS2012 make sure to select .NET Framework 4 instead of .NET Framework 4.5 in the New Project dialog

[image: New project dropdown]